# Obtener valores de json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Tengo este json

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Name": "Lï¿½nea G - Buenos Aires - Tapiales",
                "LINEA": "BELGRANO",
                "RAMAL": "G",
                "KM": 16,
                "ACTIVA": "SI",
                "CABECERAS": "González Catán",
                "SERVICIO": "Trenes urbanos",
                "CONCESION": " (Estatal, Nación)",
                "OBSERVAC": ""
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -58.39323087479187,
                        -34.64522852285068
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39493519860744,
                        -34.64593911202303
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39540370387294,
                        -34.64612018963881
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.39577715270643,
                        -34.64624297063709
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Cuando lo recorro para obtener las coordenadas

```
for feature in data['features']:
    print(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
```

El resultado que obtengo es

```
[-58.39323087479187, -34.64522852285068]
```

Y necesitaria que sea como este ejemplo

```
latitud =-58.39323087479187
longitud=-34.64522852285068
```

y asi sucesivamente con el resto de la lectura del json para todas las demas coordenadas.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar algo más? ¿Quieres decir que lo que te pasa es que no sabes extraer dos valores de una lista?

Comment: Una vez tienes las coordenadas en una variable, digamos `coor`, que es una lista con dos elementos, `coor[0]` te dal primero y `coor[1]` el segundo. Esto es bastante trivial ¿cómo llegaste a la mucho más compleja expresión `feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]` entonces?

Comment: Si, seria ese mi problema, extraer los dos valores por separado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero el JSON que has pasado esta mal formado.

Y la solución a tu problema es esta.

```
json = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "Name": "Lï¿½nea G - Buenos Aires - Tapiales",
                        "LINEA": "BELGRANO",
                        "RAMAL": "G",
                        "KM": 16,
                        "ACTIVA": "SI",
                        "CABECERAS": "González Catán",
                        "SERVICIO": "Trenes urbanos",
                        "CONCESION": " (Estatal, Nación)",
                        "OBSERVAC": ""
                    },
            "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                -58.39323087479187,
                                -34.64522852285068
                            ],
                            [
                                -58.39493519860744,
                                -34.64593911202303
                            ],
                            [
                                -58.39540370387294,
                                -34.64612018963881
                            ],
                            [
                                -58.39577715270643,
                                -34.64624297063709
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
        }
    ]

}
extra = json['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']

for x in extra:
    print("latitud ", x[0], "londtidud ", x[1])
```